# Split postgres records into groups based on time fields

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with records that look like this:

```
| id | coord-x | coord-y | time |
---------------------------------
|  1 |       0 |       0 | 123  |
|  1 |       0 |       1 | 124  |
|  1 |       0 |       3 | 125  |
```

The `time` column represents a time in milliseconds. What I want to do is find all `coord-x`, `coord-y` as a set of points for a given timeframe for a given `id`. For any given `id` there is a unique `coord-x`, `coord-y`, and `time`.

What I need to do however is group these points as long as they're `n` milliseconds apart. So if I have this:

```
| id | coord-x | coord-y | time |
---------------------------------
|  1 |       0 |       0 | 123  |
|  1 |       0 |       1 | 124  |
|  1 |       0 |       3 | 125  |
|  1 |       0 |       6 | 140  |
|  1 |       0 |       7 | 141  |
```

I would want a result similar to this:

```
| id | points              | start-time | end-time |
|  1 | (0,0), (0,1), (0,3) |        123 |      125 |
|  1 | (0,140), (0,141)    |        140 |      141 |
```

I do have PostGIS installed on my database, the times I posted above are not representative but I kept them small just as a sample, the `time` is just a millisecond timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is picking the expression inside your `GROUP BY`. If `n = 5`, you can do something like `time / 5`. To match the example exactly, the query below uses `(time - 3) / 5`. Once you group it, you can aggregate them into an array with `array_agg`.

```
SELECT
  array_agg(("coord-x", "coord-y")) as points,
  min(time) AS time_start,
  max(time) AS time_end
FROM "<your_table>"
WHERE id = 1
GROUP BY (time - 3) / 5
```

Here is the output

```
+---------------------------+--------------+------------+
| points                    |   time_start |   time_end |
|---------------------------+--------------+------------|
| {"(0,0)","(0,1)","(0,3)"} |          123 |        125 |
| {"(0,6)","(0,7)"}         |          140 |        141 |
+---------------------------+--------------+------------+
```